# Laravel Group passing Variables dynamicaly to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i'm doing a language group of routes, but all is dynamic, here are my router generator:

```
foreach(Language::All() as $language)
{
    //prefix
    Route::group(array('prefix' => $language->prefijo), function()  use ($language)
    {
        //in this i need to know the prefix
        // or passing the $language variable to controller
        Route::controller('/{menuSel}', 'RaizController');
    });
}
```

And i need to use the variable $prefix or the $language in the controller, here is my controller:

```
class RaizController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex($menuSel)
    {
        //here i have the $menuSel variable, bul also need the $language or the prefix
        return $menuSel;
    }
}
```

I'm using laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a request URI segment:

```
$language = Request::segment(1); // 1 is the index of segment
```